# Как присвоить пользователю какие-то свойства?

Tags: python, django, django-model

Задача такая - надо, чтобы пользователь мог заносить любимые игры в соответствующий раздел. Знаю, как реализовать бо́льшую часть. Но я застопорился на самом начале - как присваивать какие-то значения пользователю? Это будет полезно для модерирования (тупо меняешь свойство banned на True, и banned_level на 5, чтобы запретить и вовсе входить в аккаунт, например) и многих других задач. Все гугление сводит к "тупому" логину (аккаунт есть, а плюсы от этого?), чего я всячески пытаюсь избежать.

Comment: Попробуйте пройти туториал, и посмотреть документацию, раздел расширение моделей. Расширить можно либо так (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/) либо чреез доп модель через OneToOne. Решений уже полно и все отлично гуглится

Comment: @ZaArs документация мыльная, благо, на просторах этого сайта и его англоязычной версии я нашел ответ.